# PHP Global Exception handling across all classes

Tags: php

In PHP,is there any way to handle exceptions globally using one method? If there is, how could I do that?

I want to use the method which handles exception across all classes.

The reason that I want to achieve this is I do not want to repeat same code all the time.

Here is the example of the exception handling.

```
try {
    ***SOME CODE TO EXCUTE***
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    /* custom function to handle exception */
    $msg = exceptionHandler($e);
    $this->error(0,500, $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Comment: _Slightly_ off topic, but if you're using Composer with your project, you could use a library to provide nicer error handling capabilities - such as [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops)